# How to pass configuration parameters to a Celery task in a Flask app?

Tags: python, flask, celery, config

I am following [this tutorial](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/patterns/celery/) to create a simple Flask app to start long-running Celery tasks with http requests.

I would like to pass some configuration parameters (eg. db connection string, api keys, etc.) to a task. These are coming from a config file, not from the request. 
What is the best way to do this, and how can I access these parameters from the task?

Comment: As per answer. They are configured in the exact same way as your Flask application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could add them to your [Flask config](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/config/), import current_app from flask and use

```
current_app.config['parameter']
```

Comment: @suever They do run within an application context. That is the whole point of `ContextTask`.

Comment: @JoeDoherty Sorry, I missed that they were using the customization of the celery task in which case you're right.

Comment: I get the config file and add the contents to the app.config, then uptade the celery.conf  in the if __name__ == "__main__": block. However if I print the app.config in the task, the recently added parameters are missing.

Comment: @Balint I'm not entirely sure what you are doing there. Could you add your code to the question?